# Using onClick and React AutoBind

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I am new to React, so please feel free to redirect me to documentation if I missed out on it.

I'm trying to trigger an Ajax call using the `onClick` method as per the React tutorial. The related code is below.

```
doSomething: function() {
    // make the ajax call
},
render: function() {
    ...
    <button onClick={this.doSomething}>
        Button Title
    </button>
    <Table data={table_data}
        columns={this.props.columns}
    />
```

When the `render()` method is called, React's auto-bind method kicks in, which calls `return method.apply(component, arguments);`, and hence the ajax call is made.

The render method includes a table, and the button is also rendered for each cell (even though there is only once instance of the button for each table) and hence a network call is made for each cell as well.

Is there a better way to do something like this whereI avoid the repeated ajax calls?

Comment: In the example you posted, `this.doSomething` is *not* called, so the Ajax call is not made. Auto binding happens when the component is instantiated, not when its render method is called. On top of that, binding the methods doesn't call them. If you experience an Ajax call whenever the `render` function is called, then it's because you *are* making the Ajax call (more or less) explicitly.

Comment: @FelixKling, thank you so much for your response. According to the stack trace, after the render call, in the bind call, it returns ```method.apply(component, arguments)```, would the ```apply``` call not run the method?

Comment: `.apply` will call the function. Which stack trace are you talking about though? What makes you think you are looking at the right stack trace? How are you debugging this issue?

Comment: I'm using Chrome's debugger and break pointing inside the doSomething method before the ajax call is made. The calls before that are to render, and then bind.

Comment: And you are certain you have `{this.doSomething}` in your code, and not `{this.doSomething()}` ?

Comment: Oh crap, you're right. My bad. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The old question, but no answer.
Here it is.

You can use `arrow` function in ES6. Then you don't need to bind this function.

```
doSomething = () => {
    // make the ajax call
};
render() {
    ...
    <button onClick={this.doSomething}>
        Button Title
    </button>
    <Table data={table_data}
        columns={this.props.columns}
    />
```

It is too simple, isn't it?